# Vector2D or Vector3D in 2D games

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Is there any downside of using a Vector2D in a 2D game in Unity3d? Or should I always use a Vector3D? They seem to be interchangeable.

Comment: "They seem to be interchangeable." It doesnt only look like, Vector2 implements an implicit operator to cast from one to the other (while z gets discarded, but its still a cast). In general id say, Vector2 for UI stuff, Vector3 for everything else. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html

Comment: did you mix-up 2D and 3D in what you wrote above?  of course you use 2D in a 2D game. IF you use 3D in a 2D game, that's fine, no big problem.

Comment: I noticed the implicit cast. I was asked this question, but was not entirely sure about the answer. It's about a game that is 2D only.

Comment: just use whatever the majority of functions take as argument natively to avoid unnecessary casting. but theres so many things which can cause bad performance aside of this casts, idk if its the first place to look for optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Vector3` in 2d games. All the positions of objects are still plotted in 3 dimensional space so if you use `Vector2D` there will just be an unnecessary cast from `Vector2D` to `Vector3D`and the third dimension will just be set to 0. `Vector3D`'s `z` property is still taken into account for sprites on the same sorting layer and with the same 'order in layer' so watch out for that. For the most part the order that sprites are drawn in should be taken care of by their sorting layer and order in layer properties though.

There are quite a few uses of `Vector2D` in the 2D physics engine but you don't really have to worry about it. If you pass a `Vector3D` then it will be implicitly converted and the `z` dimension will be discarded.